# SQL Server: function as argument for another function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, function

**EDIT**: Based on answers below I added "dbo." and comments for clarification.

**Question**: How do I pass a SQL user-defined function (UDF) as an argument for another UDF? Note that the function returns a table.

```
select dbo.fn_Scalar()                      -- Returns 'sa'.
select * from dbo.fn_Tabler('sa')           -- Returns a table (not scalar).
select dbo.fn_ScalarArg(dbo.fn_Scalar())    -- Returns 'sa'
select * from dbo.fn_Tabler(dbo.fn_Scalar())    -- ERROR: Incorrect syntax near '.'.
```

(Currently using SQL Server 2008 R2)

---

**EDIT**: To ease debugging, here is the sample code to create the above functions:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[fn_Scalar]') AND type in (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT'))
DROP FUNCTION dbo.fn_Scalar
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[fn_Tabler]') AND type in (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT'))
DROP FUNCTION dbo.fn_Tabler
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[fn_ScalarArg]') AND type in (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT'))
DROP FUNCTION dbo.fn_ScalarArg
GO

create function fn_Scalar()
returns char(200) as
begin
    declare @user char(200)
    select  @user = 'sa'
    return  @user
end
GO

create function fn_Tabler(@User char(200))
returns table as
    return select @User [User]
GO

create function fn_ScalarArg(@User char(200))
returns char(200) as
begin
    declare @u2 char(200)
    select  @u2 = @User
    return  @u2
end
go
```

Comment: Does `select * from fn_Tabler(select fn_Scalar())` work?

Comment: @cdhowie: `select * from dbo.fn_Tabler(select dbo.fn_Scalar())` yields "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'" and "Incorrect syntax near ')'"

Comment: Badly worded question. You're not trying to pass a function to a function, you're trying to pass the return value of a function to a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BOL says: "Scalar-valued functions must be invoked by using at least the two-part name of the function."

```
select * from dbo.fn_Tabler(dbo.fn_Scalar())
```

EDIT:
I was wrong, there is the table-valued function... Documentation says that only constants and @local_variables can be passed to table-valued functions ([see here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx))

Comment: See my comments to Pranay Rana: fn_Tabler is not a scalar-valued function. It returns a table.

Comment: yes, I have tested on my server and retrieved the same error. See the edit for my answer.

Comment: That documentation comment is pretty well hidden in the huge document :-)

Answer (score 1):

Its working for me

```
    select [dbo].[GetOverAllWinLossDetailPointByDay] 
               (1,0,1,dbo.GetOverAllWinLossDetailPointByDay(1,0,1,1))
```

I think you forgot to add **dbo** before function name.

Comment: `select * from dbo.fn_Tabler(dbo.fn_Scalar())` yields: Incorrect syntax near '.'.